# Python pandas load csv ANSI Format as UTF-8

Tags: python, csv, pandas, decode

I want to load a CSV File with pandas in Jupyter Notebooks which contains characters like ä,ö,ü,ß.

When i open the csv file with Notepad++ here is one example row which causes trouble in ANSI Format:

```
Empf„nger;Empf„ngerStadt;Empf„ngerStraáe;Empf„ngerHausnr.;Empf„ngerPLZ;Empf„ngerLand
```

The correct UTF-8 outcome for Empf„nger should be: Empfänger

Now when i load the CSV Data in Python 3.6 pandas on Windows with the following code:

```
df_a = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
```

I get and Error Message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position xy: invalid continuation byte
```

Position 'xy' is  the position where the character occurs that causes the error message

when i use the ansi format to load my csv file it works but display the umlaute incorrect.

Example code:

```
df_a = pd.read_csv('afile.csv',sep=';',encoding='ANSI')
```

Empfänger is represented as:    Empf„nger

Note: i have tried to convert the file to UTF-8 in Notepad++ and load it afterwards with the pandas module but i still get the same error.

I have searched online for a solution but the provided solutions such as "change format in notepad++ to utf-8" or "use encoding='UTF-8'" or 'latin1' which gives me the same result as ANSI format or

```
import chardet

with open('afile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    result = chardet.detect(f.readline())

df_a = pd.read_csv('afile.csv',sep=';',encoding=result['encoding'])
```

didnt work for me.

```
encoding='cp1252'
```

throws the following exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2: character maps to <undefined>
```

I also tried to replace Strings afterwards with the `x.replace()` method but the character ü disappears completely after loaded into a pandas DataFrame

Comment: Have you tried `encoding='latin1'`?

Comment: Yes,  Empf„nger becomes: Empfnger in the displayed cell, i will edit my original question that i have tried latin1 too.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't know which are your file encoding, I think that the fastest approach is to open the file on a text editor, like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) to check how your file are encoding.

Then you go to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) and look for the correct codec to use.

In your case , ANSI, the codec is 'mbcs', so your code will look like these

```py
df_a = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=';',encoding='mbcs')
```

Comment: For someone looking into this and getting the error message `LookupError: unknown encoding: mbcs`  on a Western Europe encoding on Windows, it's because the `mbcs` encoding (the ANSI codepage) is `cp1252`. Use `encoding='cp1252'` instead. Found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482100/13371166)

Answer (score 5):

When *EmpfängerStraße* shows up as *Empf„ngerStraáe* when decoded as ”ANSI”, or more correctly cp1250 in this case, then the actual encoding of the data is most likely cp850:

```
print 'Empf„ngerStraáe'.decode('utf8').encode('cp1250').decode('cp850')
```

---

Or Python 3, where literal strings are already unicode strings:

```
print("Empf„ngerStraáe".encode("cp1250").decode("cp850"))
```

Comment: WoW! loading the file with encoding='cp850' worked, thanks a lot! 
I could not verify your example of 
`print ('Empf„ngerStraáe'.decode('utf8').encode('cp1250').decode('cp850'))` it says:  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.` 
 Did you import some special library before doing it?

Comment: @MBUser I used `print` as a statement, so this is Python 2 where `str` _has_ a `decode()` method.

Comment: @BlackJack This should be the accepted answer. I assume this comes from your repertoire? I recognize that you must been gone through many pains related to encoding :-) Somewhat related, I have been using the following cheat sheet in the past: https://bueltge.de/wk-utf-8-konvertierung/130/

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt find a proper solution after trying out all the well known encodings from ISO-8859-1 to 8859-15, from UTF-8 to UTF-32, from Windows-1250-1258 and nothing worked properly. So my guess is that the text encoding got corrupted during the export. My own solution to this is to load the textfile in a Dataframe with Windows-1251 as it does not cut out special characters in my text file and then replaced all broken characters with the corresponding ones. Its a rather dissatisfying solution that takes a lot of time to compute but its better than nothing.

Comment: A small addition: I tried to read the BOM (Byte Object Mark) with a hex editor but the file had none.

Comment: Windows-1250 worked for me (i had problems with em dashes using ISO 8859-1). But Windows-1252 also worked and will adopt it from now on :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the encoding value `UTF-16LE` to solve the problem

```
pd.read_csv("./file.csv", encoding="UTF-16LE")
```

The `file.csv` should be saved using encoding `UTF-16LE` by NotePad++, option **UCS-2 LE BOM**

Best,

Answer (score 0):

cp1252 works on both linux and windows to decode latin1 encoded files.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=';',encoding='cp1252')
```

Although, if you are running on a windows machine, I would recommend using

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';', encoding='mbcs')
```

Ironically, using 'latin1' in the encoding does not always work. Especially if you want to convert file to a different encoding.