# how to read csv files with mbcs codec in Python on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, csv, encoding, mbcs

I'm trying to read CSV files with Western Europe (windows) encoding

```
df = pd.read_csv(FileName,encoding='mbcs', usecols=[1],header=4)
```

This code works well on Windows but not on Linux 18.04. (Error: unknown encoding: mbcs)
Indeed, in the [codecs python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html), we have the information:

```
mbcs is for Windows only: Encode the operand according to the ANSI codepage (CP_ACP).
```

is there another way/name to decode my files in python on Linux? (I have thousand of files so I can't save as on Excel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your systems uses a Western Europe encoding on Windows, the `mbcs` encoding (the ANSI codepage) is `cp1252`. So you should use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(FileName,encoding='cp1252', usecols=[1],header=4)
```

on both system to have a compatible code base.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the encoding of my files are ANSI, but with 'cp1252' I have an UnicodeDecodeError: `'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 164956: character maps to <undefined>`

However it works with 'cp1252'  on windows

Comment: How is represented the `b'\x8d` byte? Could it be a `'ì'` (LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH GRAVE)

Comment: my files contain 4 lines with some "classic" text. Then bellow this lines (`header=4`) I have 2 columns `Time` and `Ampl` and then only Numerical values, but no `'ì'`. The issue was causing by 2-3 files, which seems the same than the others (maybe NaN values). Because it's data I can erase them and it works well, thx!